# Display email in richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, email, retina-display, lumisoft

I am using Lumisoft for a small E-mail project.
Everything is fine until now. I managed most of the things i wanted to achieve.
However not all of them.
I can read the bodytext of the emails but when i display them it is in plain text.
Let me show you.
When i log-in on my email on my browser the email is displayed like this:
[image]

However when i read the bodytext and display it in a richtextbox it is, as it is normal, like this:

```
New comment on your post "Spotify Ads Blocker - The best ad blocker for Spotify"
https://iblockify.wordpress.com...

Author : jc (removed , removed.dynamic.jazztel.es)
E-mail : removed@gmail.com
URL    : 
Whois  : http://whois.arin.net/removed
Comment: 
I have the same problem with another computer with OS Windows 7 x64 bit, without proxy configuration and with the .Net Framework version 4.5.1

Trash it: https://removed
Spam it: https://removed


You can reply to this comment via email as well, just click the reply button in your email client.
```

So my question is here;
What is the best solution to display the email and approche the browser's display?
I don't think i can make it 100% similar but there must be a way to make it look better than it is right now...

I am just here for some ideas so bring it on!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a RichTextBox control, try a WebBrowser control.

```
wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.DocumentText = EmailContent;
form.Controls.Add(wb);
```

etc.